# Pra que serve o atributo hreflang?

Tags: html, seo

Estou interessado em técnicas SEO e entre minhas pesquisas encontrei o atributo `hreflang`. Alguns exemplos:

```
<!-- Dentro do HEAD -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pt-br" href="...">

<!-- Dentro do BODY -->
<a hreflang="pt-br" href="...">...</a>
```

Para um site que só tem um idioma, é necessário incluir essa tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia desse atributo é indicar qual a linguagem do link da ancora onde o atributo está. Isso é util em termos de SEO para o motor de busca organizar melhor conteúdos.

Esse atributo costuma usar-se em conjunto com `rel="alternate"` para indicar que o link aponta para o mesmo conteúdo, mas noutra lingua.

Em caso de um site só com uma lingua não é necessário, aí basta ter `<html lang="pt-BR">` na tag HTML, para indicar qual a linguagem em que o site está (ainda que hoje em dia os motores de busca já não tenham problemas em detectar a língua a partir do texto do site).

Comment: Obrigado Sergio.